# Ordering Excel data for data validation (dependant dropdown lists)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I am having a little bit of problem with making dependant dropdown lists.

I want to Select the name of my Adventurer and then Select a skill. The skill should be valid and usable for that class.

Sample data :

```
Class, Name, Skill
Magic, Aldous, Fireball
Melee, Cordelia, Fury
Magic, Hmurr, Heal
Magic, Joe, Fireball
```

Each Class shares the same Skills. (eg, Magic users can choose among Fireball, Heal, Bless, Revive, etc, but Melee or Ranged users cannot, as they have their own Skills).

Each Class has a list of pre-defined Names.

It is possible to use helper columns/tables to make dependant dropdown lists, but I believe it would counterproductive, since my 3rd column does not have enough unique values.

How do you suggest I order my data?

Here's what I tried :

[Link1](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/data-validation/drop-down-lists-three-dependent.htm)

[Link2](https://www.contextures.com/exceldatavaldependindextables.html)

[Using data stored in different sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923385/combine-2-excel-tables-into-one-appending-the-data)

### Thanks for the help! Here is how it looks

[image: Here is how the names are stored]

```
=IF(E8<>"","t_dk_skill","")
```

checks if the column is filled, then it fills the cell with the given string, else leaves it blank.

[image: Here are the two LOOKUP columns]
the first column stores names, 2nd column stores class/vlookup info.

```
=
IFERROR(INDEX(tabel1,ROWS(H1:$H$1)),
IFERROR(INDEX(tabel2,ROWS(H1:$H$1)-ROWS(tabel1)),
IFERROR(INDEX(tabel3,ROWS(H1:$H$1)-ROWS(tabel1)-ROWS(tabel2)),
IFERROR(INDEX(tabel4,ROWS(H1:$H$1)-ROWS(tabel1)-ROWS(tabel2)-ROWS(tabel3)),
IFERROR(INDEX(tabel5,ROWS(H1:$H$1)-ROWS(tabel1)-ROWS(tabel2)-ROWS(tabel3)-ROWS(tabel4)),
IFERROR(INDEX(tabel6,ROWS(H1:$H$1)-ROWS(tabel1)-ROWS(tabel2)-ROWS(tabel3)-ROWS(tabel4)-ROWS(tabel5)),
IFERROR(INDEX(tabel7,ROWS(H1:$H$1)-ROWS(tabel1)-ROWS(tabel2)-ROWS(tabel3)-ROWS(tabel4)-ROWS(tabel5)-ROWS(tabel6)),"")))))))
```

nicely formatted table. [refer to this](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/28/merge-three-columns-into-one-list-in-excel/)

[image: it works!]

it works!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think want you want to do is drive both the Names and Skill named ranges based on the Class rather than having the Skills be driven by the Name. I set up my sheet to look like this:

[image: screenshot]

I created a named ranges for D3:D5 that I used for validating B2.

I also created named ranges called MagicNames, MeleeNames, RangedNames, MagicSkills, MeleeSkills and RangedSkills.

I set the validation for B3 to be based on a concatenation of the class selected and "Names"

```
=INDIRECT($B$2&"Names")
```

This then sets my named range for B3 to be equal to MagicNames, MeleeNames or RangedNames.

The validation for B4 to be based on a concatenation of the class selected and "Skills"

```
=INDIRECT($B$2&"Skills")
```

---

New answer based on comments:

[image: screenshot 2]

This time I created a list of the names with their class next to them. I created 2 named ranges; 1 for Names based on D2:D10 and another called LOOKUP that was D2:E10.

I then created named ranges for the skills for each class (G2:G4, H2:H4 etc.)

Names was used for the validation in B2. Then for the data validation on B3 I used a VLOOKUP of B2 within my LOOKUP named range.

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($B$2, LOOKUP, 2, 0))
```

This lookup returned the Class name which was then used to call the appropriate named range to list the skills.

Comment: thats a nice trick!
lets see how well it works, since I have 9 different classes with 8 unique skills for each class and 54 adventurers.
EDIT : is there a way to auto-generate the list of columns on the right?

Comment: Would it be possible to get rid of the "Class", and display only the name and the skill?

Comment: In that situation would you want a list of the 54 names in the drop down and upon picking one it would work out what class it was, and then from that class what potential skills they could use?

Comment: yes, that would be ideal! sounds like a lot of work, and i have NO idea if it can even be done.

Comment: new screenshot and explanation added; hopefully this should do you what you need it to

Comment: ok this is perfect! EDIT : i've understood the VLOOKUP, but I still dont understand how INDIRECT works.

Comment: im afraid im using a hack to get the list of Name and Class. I'm using the following link https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/28/merge-three-columns-into-one-list-in-excel/ im afraid i donot quite understand the formula, but it WORKS, even though the ROWS(H2:$H$2) part is COMPLETELY wrong.

Comment: NVM figured it out!!! used =IF(namecolumn<>"","classname",""), this auto populates the name:class table as soon as i add/remove a name. Then I used the link i posted to grab both columns and make two columns. they update just fine! thank you!